# How do I construct an Esri grid?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I read a lot of information about this subject but I can't obtain a solution about my problem.

First, I have a file with 3 columns: `X Y Z`

In MATLAB, I did this:

```
data = load('data.txt');
X = data(:,1);
Y = data(:,2);
Z = data(:,3);
```

This file is like this:

```
7037    6032    3
7036    6028    5
7037    6029    4
7037    6030    3
7038    6031    6
7039    6031    2
7037    6033    7
```

And I want to obtain the following matrix from the above matrix:

```
5   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN 4   3   NaN 3   7
NaN NaN NaN 6   NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN 2   NaN NaN
```

The rules is that the first column `Y(1) = min(Y)` , the second column `Y(2) = Y(1) + 1`. 
The first line is `X(1) = min(X)`, `X(2) = X(1) + 1`.   Essentially, the first column acts as a row index, the second column acts as a column index, and for each row and column pair, the third column gets mapped to a location in this matrix.    As such, the output matrix will be like so: `out(1,1)=X(1) Y(1)` ; `out(1,2) = X(1) Y(2)`

At the start, I think about created a matrix `out` like so:

```
xr = sort(unique(X));
yr = sort(unique(Y));
a = length(xr);
b = length(yr);
out = NaN(a,b);
```

After, with a loop, put I place this data onto this `out` matrix, but this obviously doesn't work.

For more information on an Esri grid, here's a Wikipedia article about it.  The example grid in that page is what I desire.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid

Comment: I don't see the connection between the original N x 3 matrix to the reshaped one.  Can you please add more details or clarify?  How **exactly** do you go from the original matrix to the reshaped one?  What rules or steps do you follow?  BTW, you're calling `reshape` wrong.  It accepts a matrix / vector you want to reshape, and vector that specifies how many elements are in each dimension, and `reshape` will reshape your input such that your output conforms to the dimensions specified by this vector.  That's why you're getting that scalar integer error.

Comment: Well, I don't really understand how this function work but I read on an other post someone use this one (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/263901). 

So, it's not the right function here, thank's for explanation.

Before using reshape, I try to put Z datas into a NaN matrix and well... I didn't succes to do it :(

I didn't know how to tell to Matlab to take the Z from a certain X and Y. For example in my file, how to ask Matlab to give Z number about X 7037 and Y 6030 ?

Comment: Alright, well instead of fumbling around and trying to get something to work, why don't you explain to me what it is that you would like to accomplish?  Don't focus on `reshape` -  Given your input data, explain to me what you would like accomplished and what you expect to be the output.  It may turn out you don't even need `reshape` at all.  To get even more attention, don't leave this as a comment.  Update your post to include this information.  It'll be more constructive that way.

Comment: Ok thank's. I edit my previous message. I'm going to explain without 'reshape'

Comment: No problem.  Take your time.  When you're ready, ping me and I'll read your post.

Comment: I just finish to edit the initial post

Comment: OHHH... **NOW** I know what you want.  That wikipedia link was very helpful.  I'll write an answer.... but for those who have been following around with my trend, this most definitely qualifies for Mentalist.

Comment: The rules is that Y(1) = min(Y) , Y(2) = Y(1) + 1.
X(1) = min(X), X(2) = X(1) + 1.

Z(1,1)=X(1) Y(1) ; Z(1,2) = X(1) Y(2)

Comment: I'm really sorry but I have problem to explain problem in english ^^'. I'm sorry to spend your time

Comment: I see, you want a **grid**. You may need to do something with the `X` and `Y`, if the not properly qualify to your grid, but else there is a function for this. It is called `meshgrid`. Manipulating the output will give you what you need. Type `doc meshgrid` in the command window for more info.

Comment: @Lionel - That's no problem.  I didn't even end up using that rule at all.  I've written an answer.  Good luck!

Comment: @patrik Thank's for you answer, I didn't think about meshgrid but `accumarray` is better I think (for this question)

Comment: @Lionel - I've taken the liberty in rewriting your question for future SO users.  Hope this is ok!

Comment: No problem, it's better like that ! :) All it's ok ;) Thank's a lot again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now understand what you want.  The link that you posted from Wikipedia is very useful.  You are trying to build what is known as an [Esri grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid#ASCII).  Here is a pictorial representation found on Wikipedia:

[image]

What you are given is a N x 3 matrix where the first column denotes the row IDs of this matrix, the second row denotes the column IDs of this matrix, and the third column denotes the values at each pair of IDs.  So for example, given the example above - specifically looking at the right of the figure, your text file could look like:

```
275 125 5
275 175 2
...
...
25 75 5
25 125 1
```

Each row consists of a row index, a column index and a value that maps to this location in the grid.  You had the right approach in that you should use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) - specifically the third output.  We need to obtain a unique ID for the first two columns of your data independently.  Once we do this, I'm going to show you the very powerful [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) function.  We are basically going to use the unique IDs found in the previous step, and we use these to index into our grid and place each value that corresponds to each unique pair of row and column IDs into this grid.  Therefore, your code is very simply:

```
data = load('data.txt');
%// Or you can do this for reproducing the results
%data = [7037 6032 3;
%7036 6028 5;
%7037 6029 4;
%7037 6030 3;
%7038 6031 6;
%7039 6031 2;
%7037 6033 7];

[~,~,id1] = unique(data(:,1));
[~,~,id2] = unique(data(:,2));
out = accumarray([id1 id2], data(:,3), [], [], NaN);
```

`out` produces the desired Esri grid, and we get:

```
out =

     5   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN     4     3   NaN     3     7
   NaN   NaN   NaN     6   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN     2   NaN   NaN
```

So how does this work? `accumarray` accepts in a matrix of row and column locations that you want to use to access the output.  At each of the corresponding row and column locations, you provide a value that gets mapped to this bin.  Now, by default `accumarray` **sums** up the values that get mapped to each bin, but I'm going to assume that your values in your text file are all unique in that only **one** value gets mapped to each row and column index.  Therefore, we can certainly get away with the default behaviour, and so you'd specify a `[]` for this behaviour (fourth input).  Therefore, we will use the last column of your matrix as the values that get put into this matrix, use the `[]` input to allow `accumarray` to infer the size of your matrix (third input), then any values that don't get mapped to anything, we will fill this in with `NaN`.  We aren't going to sum anything.

With the above explanation, the code follows.

Comment: Wow, thank's a lot man ! I had the logic in my head but I didn't know how to code it.

Thank's a lot I didn't know this function `accumarray`. And thank's for helping me ! :D

Comment: @Lionel - My pleasure :) Interesting problem, but totally solvable if you have the right tools.  `accumarray` is one of my favourite functions to use.  Good luck!